# What is the correct alternative to storing dynamically created classes in a global list?

Tags: python, refactoring, python-dataclasses

I am working on a project that has hundreds of dynamically created classes like

```
CLASSES = [
    make_dataclass(...),
    make_dataclass(...),
    ...
]
```

and I am using this `CLASSES` list defined in a module so that I can import groups of them instead of each one at a time (also to help out my IDE/static type checker).
Reviewers have said this is not ideal but neither me or them (nor Bing Co-pilot) know what really is the correct solution.  Something I have thought of is having a function

```
def get_classes() -> list:
    return [make_dataclass(...), ...]
```

but does this actually make any difference for the compiler?
I could also have some `ClassStore` class that has static methods which return the classes, but not sure if there is any difference there other than making the process of importing more clear.

Thanks for any tips you can provide.

Comment: What is your real question here?  Typechecking?  Performance?

Comment: What exactly does "not ideal" mean? What *specific* problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I suspect the real answer is to create each dataclass as you need it, instead of all at once.  But you haven't given enough context to know for sure.